# ASP.NET NullReferenceException for get_Session()

Tags: asp.net, session, nullreferenceexception

```
public class MessageHelper : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public MessageHelper()
    {

    }

    public string Message
    {
        set { Session["Message"] = value; }
        get
        {
            if (Session["Message"] != null)
            {
                var msg = Session["Message"] as string;
                Session["Message"] = "";
                return msg;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }

    public string ErrorMsg
    {
        set { Session["Error"] = value; }
        get
        {
            if (Session["Error"] != null)
            {
                var err = Session["Error"] as string;
                Session["Error"] = "";
                return err;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.UI.UserControl.get_Session() +15
   WebApplication1.MessageHelper.get_ErrorMsg() in ..file.master.cs:71
```

where line 71 is: if (Session["Error"] != null)

what am I doing wrong here?!

**EDIT (transcribed from original author):**

@David,

here is AdminMaster.master.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class AdminMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageHelper msg = new MessageHelper();

            if (msg.ErrorMsg != "")
            {
                // do something
            }
            if (msg.ErrorMsg != "")
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
    public class MessageHelper : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        public MessageHelper()
        {

        }

        public string Message
        {
            set { System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Message"] = value; }
            get
            {
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Message"] != null)
                {
                    var msg = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Message"] as string;
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Message"] = "";
                    return msg;
                }
                return "";
            }
        }

        public string ErrorMsg
        {
            set { System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Error"] = value; }
            get
            {
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Error"] != null)
                {
                    var err = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Error"] as string;
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Error"] = "";
                    return err;
                }
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so it does inherit from System.Web.UI.MasterPage, my bad.

i want the MessageHelper to be accessed from different pages on the site. all of my pages use the Master file, that's why i put the MessageHelper in the master file.

what is wrong here?

Comment: Session itself could be null.

Comment: @Marcie, indeed.  @NATTO, where is the code that is invoking/referencing `.ErrorMsg`?

Comment: how come? so how do i solve this error?

Comment: its protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During debugging, can you confirm that `Session` is not null?  Try referencing it fully-qualified as `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` within this class and see if that helps any.

**Edit:** In response to the non-answer answer that you posted...

It's not recommended to put that helper class in the same file as your master page.  Put it in its own file named for the class.  (There's probably debate over whether every class should have its own file, but in this particular case it's clear that the two classes in this one file are very much unrelated and shouldn't be together.)

The class can have its own namespace, such as `WebApplication1.Helpers` (though I recommend in the future using something more descriptive than `WebApplication1`, but don't try to change it here because it'll cause errors elsewhere in the project), and other class files can reference that namespace with `using WebApplication1.Helpers` in order to use that class.

Separating classes into an intuitive structure in the project (or multiple projects, as things grow in complexity) will make it easier to support in the future.

And, seeing the whole file, the helper class definitely should not inherit from `MasterPage`.  It doesn't need to, and doing so adds things to that class that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Okay, that seemed to solve the problem.. what could cause this? should I inherit from... where?!?

Comment: @NATTO: Not sure about all the details off the top of my head, but `HttpContext.Current` is something that pages have pre-referenced for you.  You're creating a separate class, and though it inherits from `MasterPage` (why, by the way?  it's strange to extend a class as something that doesn't do what it's meant to do), it doesn't seem to be aware of the `HttpContext.Current` singleton and is instead just referencing an empty `Session`.

Comment: well, I put it in a separate class because I want it to be accessed from every place, meaning the class sits on the master file, and could be accesses from different pages, am I wrong?

Comment: @NATTO: A separate class is good, and for the right reason.  What I don't see from this code is why that class inherits from `MasterPage`.  Is that `MessageHelper` class actually being used _as_ a master page?  If not, it shouldn't inherit from it.

Comment: it doesn't inherit from it.. its on the master.cs file, under the same namespace, and its defined: public class MessageHelper : System.Web.UI.MasterPage, so it inherit from System.Web.UI.MasterPage..

Comment: @NATTO: I don't follow.  In one sentence you just said that `MessageHelper` doesn't inherit from `MasterPage`, it inherits from `MasterPage`.  My point is, why does it inherit from `MasterPage`?  The code provided isn't doesn't look like it's being used as a master page.  Is it?  If it isn't, then Liskov Substitution and Single Responsibility seem to be violated here.  Better to confine the class to only what it is and only what it does.

Comment: Still don't understand the difference between Session and HttpContext.Current.Session.. anyway you saved my life!

Comment: @EmanueleGreco: There is no difference.  `Session` is just a convenient pointer to `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to achieve with the MessageHelper class.

If it is code common to your master pages then you should surely be inheriting AdminMaster from MessageHelper.

eg.

```
public partial class AdminMaster : MessageHelper
```

If not, I don't understand why MessageHelper needs to inherit from MasterPage?